# Strange form submit issue

Tags: php

I have a main layout page with a bit of logic to check for particular $_GET variable and redirect to a page based on that value.

I have added a simple form into one of the php included pages. When I set my form method to either POST or GET I get no values returned, however, if a put a link on the same page, I get all GET variables.

Here's a test code for both, the link and the form. What am I missing?

```
<a href="./?do=busSearch&zzz=999">Test link</a>

<form action="./?do=busSearch" method="POST">
    <label for="displayLimit">Display Limit</label>
    <select id="displayLimit" class="form-control">
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary mar20top">
</form>
```

Comment: You know that sending a form using the POST method makes all the values show up in the `$_POST` array, right?

Comment: And elements of form must have `name`s

Comment: `<select>` needs a `name` attribute.

Comment: Let the query variables be in hidden input fields.

Comment: What do you mean by "I get no values returned"?  Where is the code that actually uses any submitted value?  It's not really clear what steps are actually taking place here.

Comment: Yes, I tested both print_r($_POST); print_r($_GET);

Comment: Give inputs a name...

Comment: Duh... Select name is missing... @Friday

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Notice: Undefined variable and Notice: Undefined index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of your form elements have `name` attributes.  The browser uses that attribute as the key in the key/value pairs when submitting the form.  Simply add some:

```
<select id="displayLimit" class="form-control" name="someSelectElement">
```

Comment: Also, the `do` element should be an `<input name="do" type="hidden" value="busSearch" />`